# Pass attributes to sec$User entered in the Coustmer entity creation screen [cuba-platform]

Tags: cuba-platform

I'm new to Cuba-platform version 6.10.3. I have a problem where I am stuck.
I have a User entity where I create a new user which has parameters identical to those of the sec$User system entity. Now, I would like to pass the values ​​entered in the User entity (name, password, lastname, email) and also the access group created specifically for the users (customers). Then register the attributes directly in the sec$User system entity and then log into the app with the credentials of the users created with their respective permissions.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a new sec$User entity, invoke the Metadata#create() method of the `com.haulmont.cuba.core.global.Metadata` bean.
Fill necessary fields.

To save new user to the database, use DataManager bean: `com.haulmont.cuba.core.global.DataManager#commit(user)`

If you need to login to the application automatically without having user password, you can use the "trusted login" feature.

When in web client, user `com.haulmont.cuba.web.Connection` bean to login.
When in web service (e.g. portal module) - use the `com.haulmont.cuba.security.auth.AuthenticationService` service.

And call its `login` method with TrustedClientCredentials:

```
@Inject
com.haulmont.cuba.web.auth.WebAuthConfig webAuthConfig;
// ...

authenticationService.login(new TrustedClientCredentials("username", webAuthConfig.getTrustedClientPassword(), Locale.ENGLISH);
```

See also

https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.10/login.html#login_additional_eatures

https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-6.10/web_login.html

Note that web client is working under the `anonymous` user until other user logs in. So you will need to add additional permissions to the user (write access to the User entity).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the support, very helpful !